# Worksheet Formula to show if tab is hidden

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a "sheet1" and "sheet2" in Excel. I want cell A1 of "sheet1" to say `TRUE` if "sheet2" is visible and `FALSE` if "sheet2" is hidden.

I know this can be easily done with VBA, but I am wondering if it is possible to do this using a worksheet formula?

Comment: http://www.contextures.com/excel-functions-sheet-sheets.html#hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a UserDefined Function, still VBA, but you then call a formula to check,

Open your workbook.
Hit alt-f11 to get to the VBE (where macros/UDF's live)
hit ctrl-R to view the project explorer
Find your workbook.
should look like: VBAProject (yourfilename.xls)

right click on the project name
Insert, then Module
You should see the code window pop up on the right hand side

```
Option Explicit
Function IsSheetVisible(rng As Range) As Variant

Application.Volatile
IsSheetVisible = CBool(rng.Parent.Visible = xlSheetVisible)

End Function
```

Now go back to excel.
Into a test cell and type:

```
=if(issheetvisible('sheet2'!a1),TRUE,FALSE)
```

(you can use any cell on that sheet to check visibility.)

Comment: FYI the formula will not re-calculate itself on hide/unhide of a sheet etc.